# Bootstrap 4 - Collapsable Navbar Button not working/showing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

So, only recently started with Bootstrap 4 and NEVER got the collapsable Navbar  button to work properly.

Have no clue what I am doing wrong, as my own eye can't see, since everything seems fine.

Most of the code I use in this is mostly semi copy-and-paste from the official Bootstrap 4 documentation:

```
    <?php require('header.php'); ?>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">

        <a href='/' class="navbar-brand">
          <img style='max-width: 100%;' src='logo.png' />
        </a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul style="margin: 0;" class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="blog.php">Blog</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="contact.php">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <?php require('footer.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your PHP header includes all of the correct Bootstrap 4 references (added to my snippet if you need to double-check), the one other thing you're missing for your navbar is a colour scheme. That is to say, your navbar is there and functional, it's just white on white so you can't see it.

To resolve this, you can either go for the `light` theme by adding the classes `navbar-light` and `bg-light` to your navbar, or the dark theme by adding the classes `navbar-dark` and `bg-dark`. Of course, you could always go with your own colour as well, by simply setting the `background-color` of `.navbar`.

The light theme is shown here:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">

  <a href='/' class="navbar-brand">
    <img style='max-width: 100%;' src='logo.png' />
  </a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul style="margin: 0;" class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="blog.php">Blog</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.php">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And the dark theme is shown here:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">

  <a href='/' class="navbar-brand">
    <img style='max-width: 100%;' src='logo.png' />
  </a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul style="margin: 0;" class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="blog.php">Blog</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.php">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Genius!!! Thanks. First thing I did was go on the website on n my phone and spam the top of screen and it actually was there!!! Many thanks!